How do I get started with using Qwt with a Yocto Image?
I want to know the steps involved to develop Qt application that utilize Qwt source, for a remote target, or which I'm building a distribution using Yocto. Here's the guide that I've been following: Guide
I've been successful at compiling the fsl-image-qt5 recipe, and generate the rootfs, kernel and all.

Additionally, I've also been able to build and install the toolchain after following the instructions here: SDK Installation
It creates a sysroot for the architecture with all the development tools, sources and headers. Using it, I have been able to compile basic Qt programs.

Now, I want to use qwt library as well, and run the same on the target board. Looking through the internet, I can see that an official recipe is available: qwt-qt5 online reference.
I have tried the following:

Adding IMAGE_INSTALL:append = "qwt-qt5" to my local.conf file. Once done, the rootfs that is created contains a few relevant .so files(I checked by unzipping the rootfs manually). But even after repeating the toolchain installation steps shared above, I do not get any .h files, or even the .so files in the sysroot.
repopulating the SDK bitbake -c populate_sdk fsl-image-qt5. Didn't do anything either.
Manually building qwt with qmake from the sysroot. This did work but it was janky at best, and I want to streamline the process is possible.

How do I prepare my sysroot to be able to build with Qwt?
